# Какой командой удалить последние две записи в таблице SQL?

Tags: sql

Начинаю изучать SQL и не могу разобраться с таким вопросом..
Удалить последние 2 записи в таблице 'test' имеющая колонки

```
id;
review_name;
review_text;
review_author_id;
article_id.
```

SQL Сделайте свой запрос динамическим и не зависящим от значений идентификатора.

Comment: Нет такого понятия как "последние". Таблица - это несортированная куча. Соответственно необходимо указать критерий сортировки, по которому записи последние.

Comment: Кроме того, нужно знать что за БД то. Потому что в разных диалектах SQL лимит на отбор записей делается по-разному.

Comment: А `id` подряд идут или как вообще? Если подряд, то просто берёте `MAX(id)` и удаляете записи где `id >= MAX(id) - 1`. А если не подряд, то придётся через `ROW_NUMBER` изгаляться или два запроса с `MAX` делать.

Comment: Я надеюсь что да. Просто это вся информация которая есть в вопросе. Я заню как удалять определенную строку, но не понимаю как удалить именно последнюю.
Спасибо! Сейчас попробую через MAX(id) и буду ждать что мне ответят..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete from test order by id desc limit 2` подойдет, если id обладает автоматическим инкрементом

Comment: И если в этой конкретной БД есть модификатор `limit`, а он есть не во всех базах.

Comment: @CrazyElf "DELETE FROM test WHERE id IN (SELECT TOP 2 id FROM test ORDER BY id DESC)" - TOP вроде везде есть.